# Are these IP from Google's Cloud Load Balancer and if it is normal?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

`tail -n 10000 access_log | awk '{print $1}'| sor t| uniq -c| sort -nr| head -n 10`

[image]

[From Google](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https)

> The IP address of the Google Front End (GFE) that connected to the backend. These IP addresses are in the 130.211.0.0/22 and 35.191.0.0/16 ranges.

This particular web server will go down once in a while and I've been trying to pinpoint the issue but to no avail. I noticed the over 1000+ connection from 130.211.x.x. I've another web server which is also using a load balancer but they receive connections from 35.191.x.x range only. There is no reference of 130.211.x.x

Are these connections consider normal?

Comment: Do you have a Google Load Balancer configured in front of your application? If yes, then you have incorrectly configured Apache logging. Refer to @DazWilkin's answer about parsing `x-forward-for`. See this link for configuring Apache logging: https://www.techstacks.com/howto/log-client-ip-and-xforwardedfor-ip-in-apache.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All traffic to your backends will come from Google Front Ends (using IPs in those ranges); there's no other way for traffic to reach your app.

You should be able to analyze the headers (e.g. `x-forwarded-for`) in the traffic to identify its origin.

Google provides several tools to restrict access to your app to permit known users ([Cloud IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap)) and restrict bad actors ([Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor)).